# Is it possible to generate client models with url to swagger doc?

Tags: c#, swagger

I have restful api https://api2.tigerpawsoftware.com/docs/index

Is it possible to generate the model objects for C# client?

Perhaps I can generate from this json.. https://api2.tigerpawsoftware.com/docs/18.2.1/swagger

Comment: you could parse possible JSON responses from html and use something like http://json2csharp.com/ to generate models

Comment: Look at NSwag - it’s designed specifically for that.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific tool or platform or paid/free? For C#, VS2017 Professional can do it by right-clicking a C# project and selecting "Add REST API". The NSwag packages can do it by generating code at build or on demand via UI or command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. go to https://api2.tigerpawsoftware.com/docs/18.2.1/swagger
copy the entire swagger file into https://editor.swagger.io/
and click generate client in the top

you now have a full client.. feel free to extract the models if you only need these

Comment: Swagger Editor uses [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/), and Codegen also has a CLI, REST API and a Maven plugin in case you want to automate code generation.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!